# Laravel hasMany on json field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I would like to get all products related to a certian color using Eloquent 'hasMany' relationship. However the colors related to products are stored in `json` value in the products table.

Color Table:

```
-------------
id | color   
-------------
 1  Black     
 2  Brown
 3  Gray
```

Product Table:

```
------------------------------
id | name      | color
------------------------------
 1   Shoe Name   ["1","2"]
 2   Shoe Name   ["2","3"]
```

Color Model

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'color');
}
```

But unfortunately nothing returns when i do
`dd(Color::products());`

I know the issue is trying to do a `hasMany` on a json field, any help or assistance would be great. Unfortunately i won't be able to change the database structure. I need to work with it as is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to setup your own method for this. Perhaps a mutator to convert color json value to array. However any approach to solve this will be complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going on from my comment, ideally i would simply do the following:

- Create a pivot table called `product_colors` to store product & color association. So the relation will become a many-to-many.

This i would seriously recommend. Since you have written that you aren't able to alter the database structure.

For example, to retrieve list of products for a color. Your solution might be something like the following:

#### Create a mutator in your Product model that converts color json field into an array:

```
public function setColor()
{
    return json_decode($this->color, true);
}
```

#### Create a function in your Color model that retrieves a list of all products, and then filters list to return products that contains the specific color

```
public function products()
{
    return Product::all()->filter(function($product) {
        return in_array($this->id, $product->color)) ? $product : null;
    });               
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately i get a "Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation"

Comment: You may need to have a different method name like `getProductList` etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: Glad to be of help 

Comment: This would not be a good idea if you have lot of data in products table & this will load all the data in the products table. Is there any economical method, may be using WhereJsonContains() method

Comment: Yup, as others said, this is very heavy to use. You'll break your app if you have thousands of products...

Answer (score 20):

I created a package with JSON relationships: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

You can create a many-to-many relationship like this:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
       'color' => 'json'
    ];

    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToJson(Color::class, 'color');
    }
}

class Color extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function products()
    {
       return $this->hasManyJson(Product::class, 'color');
    }
}
```

Comment: I struggled whole day to use such nice package. But I am getting the following error:
require php ^7.2.5 || ^8.0 -> your php version (7.2; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.5) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan What's the result of `php -v`?

Comment: 7.2.5 I am trying to use it in my octobercms powered by laravel

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan Can you share the whole error message?

Comment: Thanks for your time: The whole error message is too long. here it is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lpiYh1x6SnLU5oeB8Za4QwUb66YqFbfoRPuGMVf1lqw/

Comment: Please create an issue on GitHub and share your whole `composer.json`: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225680/discussion-between-abdus-sattar-bhuiyan-and-jonas-staudenmeir).

Comment: This is an awesome package. Just let me know - can I cast array instead of json to use this package. i.e can I use:  protected $casts = [
        'options' => 'array',
    ]; instead of  protected $casts = [
        'options' => 'json',
    ];

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan Yes, the casts are equivalent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65339611/belongs-to-relation-with-a-json-column-in-laravel  @Jonas Staudenmeir would you have a look at this please?