# Laravel HasMany relationship with json column

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function test()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MultiTenant::getModel('TestModel'), 'value', 'data->variable');
}
```

I'm trying to get key value from json column and get related objects but this

> data->variable

doesn't work, any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel hasMany on json field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222856/laravel-hasmany-on-json-field)

Comment: I want to know, if it is possible with this relationship, not filtring and running other queries

Comment: I created a package with JSON relationships: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you are attempting to retrieve a JSON object, and after doing this, attempting to retrieve the variable value from the data JSON object? In this case, rather than doing

> return $this->hasMany(MultiTenant::getModel('TestModel'), 'value', 'data->variable');

You might want to do

> return $this->hasMany(MultiTenant::getModel('TestModel'), 'value', 'data')->variable;

If that doesn't work, check what this actually returns:

> return $this->hasMany(MultiTenant::getModel('TestModel'), 'value', 'data');

EDIT: Changed to actually check for data.