# Belongs to relation with a json column in laravel

Tags: laravel

> This is an awesome package:
> https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations But I can't
> make it work with couple of days struggle. Let me explain my situation
> and my approach.

orders table has json type column named `sender_address` with the following value:

```
{
  "title":"office",
  "street":"Mohakhali Flyover",
  "lat":"23.7794099",
  "lng":"90.3983494",
  "district":"1",
  "area":"2"
}
```

**My Order Model Definition:**

```
class Order extends Model
{
  use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;
    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'orders';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    
    protected $casts = [
     "sender_address" => "array"
    ];

    public $belongsTo = [
        'client' => [ '\ItScholarBd\Api\Models\User'],
        'customer' => [ 'ItScholarBd\Order\Models\Customer'],
        'district' => [ 'ItScholarBd\Location\Models\District'],
        'clientArea' => [ '\ItScholarBd\Location\Models\Area','sender_address->area']
      ];
}
```

Usage:

```
$records   =   Order::with(['client.company','clientArea'])->get();
```

Here I just want to get `\ItScholarBd\Location\Models\Area` data matching with `sender_address->area`. But `$records` show the following data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [number] => AWB2000001
            [sender_address] => Array
                (
                    [title] => office
                    [street] => Mohakhali Flyover
                    [lat] => 23.7794099
                    [lng] => 90.3983494
                    [district] => 1
                    [area] => 2
                )

            [client_id] => 309
      
            [client] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 309
                    [name] => client
                    [email] => client@gmail.com
                    [password] => $2y$10$BIQgKvOV4h0lWOO66W6CC.rCEnFB6c6mBCh3WF2t1eDFueEJmgb7y
                    [activation_code] => 
                    [persist_code] => $2y$10$1Njt/420DYIyW3azOYh9z./WwURdgFf.7JKCGE0jqjTQmBPK/nmSe
                    [reset_password_code] => 
                    [permissions] => 
                    [is_activated] => 1
                    [activated_at] => 2020-11-27 18:41:04
                    [last_login] => 2020-12-17 13:50:48
                    [created_at] => 2020-11-27 18:41:04
                    [updated_at] => 2020-12-17 13:50:48
                    [username] => client
                    [surname] => 
                    [deleted_at] => 
                    [last_seen] => 2020-12-17 16:55:42
                    [is_guest] => 0
                    [is_superuser] => 0
                    [phone] => 
                    [company] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => Bracnect  Academy
                            [email] => academy@bracnet.net
                            [url] => https://academy.bracnet.net/
                            [phone] => 01708006884
                            [alt_phone] => 01709007885
                            [address] => mohakhali
                            [product_type] => Course
                            [created_at] => 2020-12-02 16:20:54
                            [updated_at] => 2020-12-02 16:22:23
                            [code] => bracnectacademy
                        )
                )

            [client_area] => 
        )

)
```

Here client_area is empty. But I double the areas table where a records exist with `id = 2`. What's wrong in my approach? I am struggling with this issue for 2 days. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen anyone define relationships this way nor did I find it in the documentation:

```
public $belongsTo = [
         'client' => [ '\ItScholarBd\Api\Models\User'],
         'customer' => [ 'ItScholarBd\Order\Models\Customer'],
         'district' => [ 'ItScholarBd\Location\Models\District'],
         'clientArea' => [ '\ItScholarBd\Location\Models\Area','sender_address->area']
       ];
```

I think if you define the relationships in this way:

```
public function clientArea(){
  return $this->belongsTo('\ItScholarBd\Location\Models\Area', 'sender_address->area');
}
```

it should work.

And dont forget to use the `HasJsonRelationships` trait in the Area model as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. how can I apply this relationship? is it Order::with(['client.company'])-clientArea()->get();  ?

Comment: Order::with(['client.company', 'clientArea''])->get(). You need to add the relation function name. Please check what is the return value of this statement: Order::find(1)->clientArea.